# Problem accessing sql server database 2008 r2 over network

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I've just finished my c# application with sql database built in 2008 r2 version

I wanted to share this database over LAN and my connection string is :

```
ConnectionString = @"Data Source=192.168.0.1,1433\SQLEXPRESS;user id=Rula; password=marojo;AttachDbFilename=\\192.168.0.1\Release\WEPA.mdf;Connection Timeout=30;Integrated Security=SSPI;user instance=true";
```

where 192.168.0.1 is the IP of the computer hosting the sqlexpress instance

when I connect to database locally from the hosting computer I get no errors, but when I try to connect to the database from the shared application I get the following error:

User doesn't have permission to perform this action.

while I mapped the GUEST user to my database on the hosting machine since I knew that if a computer try to connect to database remotly, it connect as guest.

notice: I have my application and database shared over network in the same folder, and again locally everything is ok

Please what can I do to solve this problem ????
thanks in advance =-)

Comment: Never, ever, ever use the GUEST user account.  It should be completely turned off.  The ONLY time you should have it on is if you really don't care who connects to your database.. Which is a situation I have yet to see in real life.  Quite frankly I wish they would just remove the thing completely.

Comment: Thanks Chris ....

it was a default choice that the user is Guest when I was hosting database on windows 7
but now I don't know which user who doesn't have permissions?? and if so how to change default choice???
cuz I tried every thing and every user and still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved !!

there was just attaching problem when the database is attached to sql server management studio it's attached as an old name or related to the computer it's copied from

Thank you everyone for your effort : )

Answer (score 3):

If the 2 machines are not on the same domain this will fail. You might want to use sql logins

Comment: Thaanks alot Ali : )
I'm working on the same work group and when I tried hosting the database on windows 7 everything was fine and I was able to login as guest account by default which I gave permissions.

but now on windows XP I don't know which user accessing database it's not guest

Answer (score 1):

The guest account would not be used in an trusted connection.  The integrated connection uses the user account attached to the process using the connection string.
http://forums.asp.net/t/822604.aspx/1

If you wanted to use integrated security, the web server would need to be configured to digest logins and then you would need to grant access to all (potential) authenticated users access to the database.  This is typically not done due to the unnecessary complexity you are adding to the process.  Just use sql links like Ali stated and be done with it.

Comment: Thaanks Mutek : )
as I said I tried to run my application the same way on windows 7 which allowed logins as guest .. for examply when I tried to to connect to database hosted on windows 7 I got a message saying that accout guest doesn't have permissions ... but when I set permissions to guest account everything gone the way I want.

Comment: but moving to windows XP allowed this error message to appear 
user doesn't have permission to perform this action

what I want to know exactly which user doesn't have permission ???

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I see a couple things that are wrong in your connection string.

Namely, you have defined a user id and password... then you go on to set the Integrated Security flag.  These are mutually exclusive.  Either it connects as the same user that the app is executing under (most likely the app pool user account) OR it connects as the user defined in your connection string.

The reason you see a difference between 7 and XP is simply that one is defaulting to using the user id / password, the other is defaulting to using integrated security.

I suggest that you visit http://www.connectionstrings.com/ in order to build a proper connection string.

**Update:**

Other things I see.  First, AttachDbFilename can only work with integrated security.  Obviously that isn't a possibility, so you need to get rid of that parameter and configure sqlexpress directly on the server to target that database file.

Second, User Instance is for desktop deployments.. not servers.  Get rid of it as well because it's going to be a huge memory hog.

Third, read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you Chris I know that Integrated security and specifying user id are mutually exclusive .. but when integrated security is used, user id and password are ignored ;)
About windows xp defaulting using user id and password ,, when I tried to make integrated security set to false and user instance set to false and mapped login to database a different message appeared which is:
cannot attach database ...... another database exist bla bla bla
how can I solve this problem since logging in as user doesn't allow creating user instance ???
thanks for your effort : )

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few reasons this could be happening:

1. SQL Browser service not turned on
2. Connection string using a trusted connection and you are not set up as that user (check what user your code is using by getting User from the current context)
3. You do not have the same protocols set up on the client (less likely)

Since it is a permissions issue, you will most likely have to set up your windows domain account in the database to use it. If that is not an option for the application users, then you may desire to move to a sql account rather than windows accounts.

Comment: Thanks Gregory : )

my sqlbrowser service is turned on and database is set to allow remote connections.. I tried to move to sql account and I added new login ...
but what I get is "cannot create user instance when logged in from sql account"
and when I remove "user instance=true" from connection string I get an error similar to this "a database with same name exist...."
any solution ??